# Wait for ModuleCatalog to finish loading a module

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Is it possible to wait for the ModuleCatalog to finish loading a module and then sending a event?

Answer (score 1):

In order to know when a module finish loading, the **ModuleManager** provides an event of ***LoadModuleCompleted*** which you could handle by referencing from the **IModuleManager** interface:

```
this.moduleManager.LoadModuleCompleted += this.ModuleManager_LoadModuleCompleted;
```

So then, you would handle the related tasks on the `ModuleManager_LoadModuleCompleted(object sender, LoadModuleCompletedEventArgs e)` method.

The following **MSDN Prism Guide** section describes this feature of the ModuleManager:

- [Detecting When a Module has been Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec37)

For further information, you could look for the **Modularity Quickstart** which shows how this event could be used. Find the Quickstart available for download in the following link:

- [Modularity QuickStarts for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921068%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

I hope this helped you,
Regards.

Comment: Does the ModuleCatalog utilize the ModuleManager to load the single Modules? I need this mostly for the loading notifications of a SplashScreen.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are asking if one event is raised for each loading module. This would be correct, and you could see this behaviour on the ModularityWithUnity Quickstart which records the module names for each Module by the time that it get loaded (**ModuleManager_LoadModuleCompleted** handler method is implemented at *Shell.xaml.cs* Modularity QuickStart). Regarding your question, the **ModuleManager** initializes the **ModuleCatalog** and it then loads every available module from the **ModuleCatalog**. You may see this in the Prism Library source at ModuleManager.cs class.